# slimv - error connecting to clojure swank server

Tags: vim, clojure, macvim, swank, slimv

Tried to get slimv running today, but ran into an issue. These are the steps I went through:

- Installed clojure 1.3.0: `brew update && brew install clojure`
- Setup swank-clojure: `lein plugin install swank-clojure 1.3.3`
- Cloned slimv: `hg clone ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/kovisoft/slimv`
- Restarted macvim, opened existing clojure project, verified the slimv menu shows up
- Started a swank server with `lein swank`
- Tried to connect to it from macvim. This error showed up in the terminal that was running swank:

  ```
  exception in read loop
  java.lang.Exception: Error reading swank message
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
  at clojure.lang.Compiler$NewExpr.eval(Compiler.java:2100)
  at clojure.lang.Compiler$DefExpr.eval(Compiler.java:361)
  at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5429)
  at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:5857)
  at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:340)
  at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:331)
  at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:409)
  at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:381)
  at clojure.core$load$fn__4519.invoke(core.clj:4915)
  at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:4914)
  at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
  at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:4729)
  at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:4766)
  at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
  at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:542)
  at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:4804)
  at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
  at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:544)
  at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:4892)
  at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:436)
  at swank.core.connection$eval174$loading__4414__auto____175.invoke(connection.clj:1)
  at swank.core.connection$eval174.invoke(connection.clj:1)
  at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5424)
  at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5415)
  at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:5857)
  at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:340)
  at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:331)
  at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:409)
  at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:381)
  at clojure.core$load$fn__4519.invoke(core.clj:4915)
  at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:4914)
  at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
  at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:4729)
  at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:4766)
  at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
  at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:542)
  at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:4804)
  at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
  at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:544)
  at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:4892)
  at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:457)
  at swank.core$eval46$loading__4414__auto____47.invoke(core.clj:1)
  at swank.core$eval46.invoke(core.clj:1)
  at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5424)
  at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5415)
  at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:5857)
  at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:340)
  at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:331)
  at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:409)
  at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:381)
  at clojure.core$load$fn__4519.invoke(core.clj:4915)
  at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:4914)
  at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
  at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:4729)
  at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:4766)
  at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
  at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:542)
  at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:4800)
  at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
  at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:544)
  at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:4892)
  at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:512)
  at swank.swank$eval40$loading__4414__auto____41.invoke(swank.clj:1)
  at swank.swank$eval40.invoke(swank.clj:1)
  at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5424)
  at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5415)
  at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:5857)
  at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:340)
  at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:331)
  at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:409)
  at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:381)
  at clojure.core$load$fn__4519.invoke(core.clj:4915)
  at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:4914)
  at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
  at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:4729)
  at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:4766)
  at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
  at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:542)
  at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:4800)
  at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
  at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:542)
  at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:4881)
  at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
  at user$eval27.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
  at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5424)
  at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5415)
  at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5391)
  at clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2382)
  at clojure.main$eval_opt.invoke(main.clj:235)
  at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:254)
  at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:279)
  at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:354)
  at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
  at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:369)
  at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)
  at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:482)
  at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
  ```

Any ideas? I also tried using swank-clojure 1.2.1 and clojure 1.2.

Comment: also see for an answer, fyi: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525519/slimv-segfaulting-on-os-x-lion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a python related problem in macvim (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525519/slimv-segfaulting-on-os-x-lion) thread for example). Some macvim snapshots work, some don't. A user tried to compile a snapshot that was segfaulting with python support linked against 2.6 instead of 2.7, and it solved the crashes. So it must be a problem with the python 2.7 binding, try to change it to 2.6 if you can.

You can verify the python version from within vim via this command:

```
:python import sys
:python print sys.version_info
```

However, I'm not sure you have the same problem, as you did not mention any segfaults, but maybe the difference is that you use clojure instead of clisp.

Comment: Python version is 2.7.1 final. If I launch mvim from terminal, I see "Vim: Caught deadly signal SEGV Vim: Finished." after lein swank throws an exception.

Comment: I've just received the following information from the macvim developer:

It seems this is a 64 bit issue -- compiling MacVim 32 bit appears to fix it. Please compile a 32 bit version. Build instructions are [here](https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/wiki/Building), in order to build 32 bit the "configure" line must include the flag "--with-macarchs=i386".

Comment: A new macvim snapshot (63) has just been released which is 32 bit. It can be downloaded instead of trying to build from sources. There is a link to it on the [change log page](https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/wiki/ChangeLog).

Comment: Thank you, Tamas. I'll see if I can get it working with snapshot 63.

Answer (score 1):

Today(2012.05.15)

```
brew install macvim
```

can't work Slimv(64bit).

But install from http://code.google.com/p/macvim/ Download MacVim 7.3 (snapshot 64) for Mac OS X Lion. (Released Jan 2, 2012.), though I tried only ccl & sbcl, it works! If you use OS X Lion, please try it.