# MacVim: slimv does not start

Tags: vim, lisp, macvim, slime, slimv

I'm using MacVim (kind of gvim for OSX) and try to get the [slimv](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2531) plugin running.
Sadly it's not working out of the box. In fact, it does not start up at all.

My setup:

- MacVim (32bit [cause of this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8028410/1185999)) (vim 7.3)
- **:scriptnames** does not list `ftplugin/slimv.vim` while `plugin/paredit.vim` is listed
- **:set ft?** shows `filetype=lisp` for .lisp files
- **:messages** shows no errors
- **:filetype** `filetype detection:ON  plugin:ON  indent:ON`
- **:echo g:paredit_loaded** `1`
- **:echo g:slimv_loaded** `E121: Undefined variable: g:slimv_loaded \ E15: Invalid expression: g:slimv_loaded`
- compiled with +python (2.7)

SBCL and slime are installed - works flawless with emacs.
I tried it with and without `let g:slimv_swank_cmd = ...` in .vimrc and changed the line recommended on the plugin page from

```
let g:slimv_swank_cmd = '!osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"sbcl --load ~/.vim/slime/start-swank.lisp\""'
```

to

```
let g:slimv_swank_cmd = '!sh -c "sbcl --load /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/slime/start-swank.lisp" &'
```

since the osascript was not working and I don't know how to fix it. But a similar call to xterm is sufficient for Linux so my sh call should be fine.
Well, I got no idea what to try next. :/

**The problem got solved** by installing slimv to ~/.vim instead of the vim ebedded in MacVim. Maybe some kind of bug? However, Common Lisp + vim - I just love it.

Comment: If I remember correctly from when I set up slimv, VIM can't be the parent process of the inferior LISP.  Emacs has a concept of child processes, but VIM doesn't.  So you need to start the instance of LISP from somewhere else.  That's why the default has an `osascript` command -- that opens a new Terminal window which owns the LISP session.

Comment: Using the default command doesn't open a Terminal (nothing happens) and even starting the process by hand does not help.

Comment: In my `.vimrc` file, I have `g:slimv_swank_cmd = "! osascript -e 'tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"/sw/opt/sbcl-1.0.47/bin/sbcl --load ~/.vim/slime/start-swank.lisp\"'"` -- you have to tell Terminal to run the script, not MacVIM like your first line shows.  Alternately, try running the `sbcl --load .../start-swank.lisp` command in a Terminal window first and then starting slimv.  It should be able to connect to an already-running instance instead of starting its own.

Comment: osascript itself is working, you are right. I replaced my approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because moving the slimv plugin to `~/.vim` fixed it, I suspect the problem is that MacVim's default `/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/ftplugin/lisp.vim` is being sourced before the `ftplugin/lisp/slimv-lisp.vim` file provided with slimv.

Both of those files (`lisp.vim` and `slimv-lisp.vim`) start with code like this:

```
" Only do this when not done yet for this buffer
if exists("b:did_ftplugin")
    finish
endif

" Don't load another plugin for this buffer
let b:did_ftplugin = 1
```

and so whichever file gets sourced first will prevent the other file from running since vim does `finish` (exits the script) if it detects that another *lisp*.vim script was run previously and therefore set the `b:did_ftplugin` buffer-local variable.

You can tell this is happening by running MacVim from the command line with the arguments:

```
-V20macvim-log.txt hello.lisp
```

Then quit the MacVim session that starts up, and look at the macvim-log.txt file it created.

Search for `b:did_ftplugin` and you'll see it referenced each time `lisp.vim` or `slimv-lisp.vim` runs, and you can see that `lisp.vim` runs first, which prevents `slimv-lisp.vim` from working.

Moving your slimv install from the `/Applications/MacVim.app/` dir to your `~/.vim` dir will change the order so that `slimv-lisp.vim` is sourced before `lisp.vim`, and then slimv will work.

Answer (score 2):

If slimv.vim is not listed in `:scriptnames` and `g:slimv_loaded` is undefined then you don't have the plugin loaded at all. I guess you don't have filetype plugins enabled. Paredit is a general plugin but slimv.vim is a filetype plugin and filetype/indent plugins must explicitly be enabled. Try to add these lines to your `.vimrc`:

```
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on
```

Comment: Both are added to my .vimrc without success. However, the problem got solved by installing the plugin to ~/.vim instead of MacVim's embedded vim. Nevertheless thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem got solved by installing slimv to ~/.vim instead of the vim ebedded in MacVim. Maybe some kind of bug?
However, Common Lisp + vim - I just love it.